# media->save gives erros

Tags: 8, media

I am able to create a media object with the below code

```
 $static_media = Media::create([ 
'bundle' => 'document', 
'uid' => $current_userid , 
'langcode' => "en",
'status' => 1, 
 'name' => [
    'target_id' =>$title,

  ],
$file_name => [ 'target_id' => $fid, 'alt' => $title, 'title' => $title, ], ]);
```

but when I try to do `$result=$static_media->save();`  I get the error

```
Error: `Call to a member function isEmpty() on null in Drupal\media_entity_document\Plugin\MediaEntity\Type\Document->getField() (line 43 of profiles\lightning\modules\contrib\media_entity_document\src\Plugin\MediaEntity\Type\Document.php).
```

How can I debug this to find out what is missing?  I tried putting an echo at that point of the code in the plugin but cannot see anything .  What would you suggest to try to see what field it is looking for at that point?

Thank you .

Comment: Look at what is calling isEmpty and that ought to give you an idea of what it is expecting

Comment: Its the function geField () but when I put in echos in that function there is nothing there .  so i still dont know what field is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this part of the array

```
$file_name => [ 'target_id' => $fid, 'alt' => $title, 'title' => $title, ], ]);
```

i had to put the field name , not the file name.

```
'field_document' => [ 'target_id' => $fid, 'alt' => $title, 'title' => $title, ], ]);
```